# Objects are not valid react child when using React.createElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simple text component:

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface IProps {
  level: 't1' | 't2' | 't3',
  size: 's' | 'm' | 'l' | 'xl' | 'xxl',
  subtle?: boolean,
  children: any,
}

const textSize = (size) => {
  if (size === 's') {
    return 'f6'
  }
  if (size === 'm') {
    return 'f5 fw3'
  }
  if (size === 'l') {
    return 'f4 fw5  lh-2'
  }
  if (size === 'xl') {
    return 'f3 fw5 lh-2 ls-025 ma0'
  }
  if (size === 'xxl') {
    return 'f2 fw5 lh-title ls-03125 ma0 mb3'
  }
}

const elements = {
  t1: 'h2',
  t2: 'h1',
  t3: 'span',
};


export const Text = ({ children, level, size, subtle, ...props }: IProps) => {
  return React.createElement(
    elements[level] || elements.t3,
    {className: textSize(size)},
    props,
    children,
  );
}
```

Which is used like so:

```
    <Text
      size='s'
      level={'t3'}>
        Hello world
    </Text>
```

However, when the line `{className: textSize(size)},` is included in the main component I get the following error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in span in Unknown`

Any ideas what can cause this?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mountain-uwroo?file=/src/index.tsx)

Comment: why do you have curly brackes {} wrapping this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.createElement` takes 3 arguments, and you try to pass 4.

> React.createElement(component, props, ...children)

In your case `{className: textSize(size)}` becomes `props`, and your `props` is actually `children`. You probably need to do something like

```
return React.createElement(
    elements[level] || elements.t3,
    {...props, className: textSize(size)},
    children,
  );
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, unfortunately the error still persists. I've updated the question with a Codesandbox